# NX Server lower-case d minimizes from OS X Client?

Tags: linux, mac-osx, x11, nx

I've installed NX Server on Ubuntu Maverick Meerkat (10.10) using the instructions found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX

I have a problem using the default NX Client for OS X (10.6) downloaded from the nomachine website.

When using the OS X client, every time I hit the lowercase d key in the NX session window whatever remote window I'm using minimizes. This only happens in OS X, from the Windows client I have no such problem. This happens from two different OS X machines, so it's unlikely to be a local setting.

Comment: It turns out lower-case d is minimizing ALL applications. Upper-case D works normally (i.e. inserts 'D')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it. NX client seems to assign it's own shortcuts - but only on Ubuntu 10.10 does it assign minimize all windows to the 'd' character. Change it server side when logged in via the NX Client and the problem is fixed.

Under Settings > Key Mappings > Minimize All Windows. It won't let you disable it, so just choose a key combo you'll never use (I chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.)

Answer (score 3):

You can disable it by 'assgining' Backspace as the new shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Ubuntu 10.10 too.  Whenever I pressed d on the keyboard it minimized all the windows.  I fixed it by going into System --> Preferences --> Keyboard Shortcuts and disabling the shortcut that was setup to use the D key press.

Answer (score 1):

The setting I had to disable d for in Ubuntu 10.10 was "Hide all normal windows and set focus to the Desktop"

As Kyle said in another reply, use Backspace to disable the shortcut

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me but the tip [here](http://larsmichelsen.com/open-source/fixing-show-desktop-shortcut-hotkey-in-ubuntu-11-10/) did for Ubuntu 11.10.  After I made the change, I had to restart.